# Matlab add native libraries to path programmatically

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

**Background**

I have a Matlab codebase (or *App* now with r2012b), that I distribute to users.

This app uses JNI with native libraries (several *.dll* files).  On my local machine, this requires entries in a *librarypath.txt* or *javalibrarypath.txt* (r2012b) file, as described by [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html?s_tid=doc_12b) and [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-installation-take-2/).

**Question**

Is there any way to add native libraries to the Matlab java class path programmatically?

I would like to write an *initMyLibrary.m* script, whereby:

- Users don't have to modify these files manually.
- The code can be be used as a compiled MCR application.
- The init doesn't destroy users's existing *javalibrarypath.txt*.
- Assume no admin rights (can't modify the Matlab base installation).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this might be messy and I'm not an expert in the matter, but wouldn't something like this work in your *initMyLibrary.m*:

```
currentdir = pwd; % or any other directory you know the dll will be in
if ispc
    system(['setx path "%path%;' currentdir '"']); % only works from windows 7 onwards though, for xp or vista youll have to change the registry with reg
elseif isunix
    system(['export PATH=$PATH:' currentdir]); % dont know if this works without admin rights though...
elseif ismac
    % for mac I dont know how to do this without admin rights
else
    error('whatever') % error handling
end
```

Because I think if your dll is on the system path this should be fine no? Don't forget to restore the path at the end of the application.

Anyway all of this might be a little dangerous...

Comment: Close but still some challenges. The $PATH variable is read during launch, so this would mean that the first time it would require a restart.  It would also need a wrapper that checks that the .dll is not already on the path.  I plan to leave the question open for a bit longer...

Comment: Oops sorry I edited my question without noticing your comment. Yeah I guess your remarks are right for the first version of my answer, but would changing the registry with `setx` of `reg` get this to work? (for windows anyway... Unix and mac systems might need some research)